# While running collator with our paraId having error

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rococo, parachain-collator, substrate-parachain-template

We were trying to run collator with our paraID registered on polkadot. We are able to connect with the same process on rococo test network. But while we are connecting with polkadot. It's throwing these errors. The command to connect with polkadot live we are using is

```
./target/release/parachain-collator
--collator
--force-authoring
--chain polkadot-raw.json
--base-path /tmp/parachain/vineet
--port 40333
--ws-port 8844
--
--execution wasm
--chain polkadot.json
--port 30343
--ws-port 9977
```

```
2022-07-15 18:28:15 [Relaychain] Failed to fetch runtime API data for job err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "validator_groups", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_validator_groups is not found"))) } 
2022-07-15 18:28:15 [Relaychain] Failed to fetch basics from runtime API relay_parent=0x91b171bb158e2d3848fa23a9f1c25182fb8e20313b2c1eb49219da7a70ce90c3 err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) } 
2022-07-15 18:28:15 [Relaychain] Our view contains 0x91b1…90c3, but not in active heads added=0x91b1…90c3 
2022-07-15 18:28:15 [Relaychain] error=RollingSessionWindow(SessionsUnavailable { kind: RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }), info: None }) 
2022-07-15 18:28:15 [Relaychain] error=Sender(Runtime(RuntimeRequest(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }))) ctx="on FromOrchestra"

2022-07-15 18:28:52 failed to associate send_message response to the sender
```

Comment: Are you using Cumulus or substrate-parachain-template? And what version of Polkadot and/or release are you using? `polkadot-v0.9.25`? Do you have a repo you can link to?

Comment: Hi @Bruno, Thanks for replying. I am using `substrate-parachain-template` and we are trying to connect with polkadot live.

we have used 
`git clone --depth 1 --branch polkadot-v0.9.24 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template`
For start.

We modified the `substrate-parachain-template` as per our need and trying to run the collator.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to run a customized collator to a parachain that is live on Polkadot? I would need to see your code and know which parachain you want to collate for in order to replicate this issue on my machine. Can you successfully run a collator using the parachain's code instead of the `substrate-node-template`?

Answer (score 1):

Your command to run a collator is fine. In regards to this error:

```
[Relaychain] Failed to fetch runtime API data for job err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "validator_groups", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_validator_groups is not found"))) }
```

There is an open issue for this:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/1293#issuecomment-1137160459

In regards to the `failed to associate send_message response to the sender` message, I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/1467

Regardless of these messages, you should still be able to sync with Polkadot and collate with your command.